# Getting CLLocation course and translate to user

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocation

I'm trying to get information about the direction taken by the user (N-S-W-O) via CLLocation's course method.
I'm using this code:

```
double course;
bool isNord;

course = currentLocation.course;
NSLog(@"Current course: %f", course);
NSInteger courseString = course;
//_labelCompass.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", courseString];

if (courseString == -1) {
    _labelCompass.text = @"N/A";
}
if (courseString >= 22 && courseString <= 67) {
    isNord = false;
    _labelCompass.text = @"NE";
}
if (courseString >=67 && courseString <= 112) {
    isNord = false;
    _labelCompass.text = @"E";
}
if (courseString >= 112 && courseString <= 157) {
    isNord = false;
    _labelCompass.text = @"SE";
}
if (courseString >= 157 && courseString <= 208) {
    isNord = false;
    _labelCompass.text = @"S";
}
if (courseString >= 208 && courseString <= 247) {
    isNord = false;
    _labelCompass.text = @"SW";
}
if (courseString >= 247 && courseString <= 292) {
    isNord = false;
    _labelCompass.text = @"W";
}

if (courseString >= 292 && courseString <= 337) {
    isNord = false;
    _labelCompass.text = @"NW";
}

if (isNord == true) {
    _labelCompass.text = @"N";
}
```

Of course I'm putting this into

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

and the course information is update successfully.
Using this algorithm I cannot know when the course is North like I do for the others so I've built this.
There are any other methods better than this?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrong thing is that with `<= 67` of the first if and the second `>= 67` of the second if, if the value is 67, ALWAYS the first if will be triggered.
Also, as stated by [rmaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1226963/rmaddy) please use `else if`, it's kind more efficent.
Finally use the best syntax `min < myVal && myVal < max` to emulate the Mathematical range `min < MyVal < max`.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you determine of the course is North? Just do:

```
if (course < 22 || course > 337) {
    _labelCompass.text = @"N";
}
```

BTW - please use `else if`. It will be far more efficient:

```
if (courseString == -1) {
    _labelCompass.text = @"N/A";
} else if (courseString >= 22 && courseString <= 67) {
    _labelCompass.text = @"NE";
} else if (courseString >=67 && courseString <= 112) {
```

Comment: Of course I tried these ways (both course < 22 || course > 337 and else if) but then the app prints nothing in the textlabel if the course was between that interval

Comment: Then you must have had something wrong. What I posted will work just fine.

Comment: The code I used is what you read, maybe the "=" May be the wrong thing?

Comment: Get rid of the `isNord` check. Add the `if (course < 22 || course > 337)` check for North. Then add the `else` statements to make it more efficient. It is correct.

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationManager has an heading option with an heading update Delegate.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager 
didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading
```

newHeading has a property 'magneticHeading':

0 is north, 
90 is east, 
180 is south, 
270 is west

Comment: Does didUpdateHeading uses the iPhone's built-in magnetometer?

Comment: According to the documentation it is: Devices with a magnetometer can report the direction in which a device is pointing, also known as its heading.
Devices with GPS hardware can report the direction in which a device is moving, also known as its course.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/GettingHeadings/GettingHeadings.html

Comment: My app will stay in background while speed and other things are sent via BT to a Pebble Smartwatch, place an iPhone in your pocket and use the magnetometer doesn't seems to be the right method to get where the user is going